# C++ - How can I initialize a ref type with a literal?

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I'm trying to make my own String class, for a personal project. The project runs inside the .NET framework, so it's necessary for it to be a ref class.

I'd like to be able to initialize it with a const char* constant, just like System::String:

```
String^ str = "Hello World"; //Works fine
```

However, when I try to initialize my custom string class, I get the following error:

```
BString^ bstr = "Hello World"; //Error

1   IntelliSense: a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "BString ^"
```

The relevant class code is as follows:

```
public ref class BString
{
public:
    BString(const char* InitializerString) {
        str = InitializerString;
    }

    BString^ operator=(const char* c) {
        return gcnew BString(c); //I thought an overloaded operator might have resolved the issue, but no such luck.
    }

private:
    const char* str;
};
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: It is `static operator BString ^ (const char* rhs)`.  That compiles and executes just fine but the IntelliSense parser still rains on your parade.  That sucks.

Comment: So basically what I'm trying to achieve could be accomplished if not for IntelliSense? That really does suck :/